# Loading controller js files using require.js

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I am learning to implement require.js to load the necessary javascript files. I am able to load java script files using require.js which in replace of `<script>` tags. Even though I am able to load the js files, the content inside the files are not accessible and getting the error saying 'CarApp module not found'. How would this makes the difference?

My `index.html` where I load require.js

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>My App</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/vendor/bootstrap-2.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" media="screen">
<script src="/vendor/angularjs-1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/angularjs-1.0.5/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

<script data-main="/js/main" src="/js/require.js"></script>

<div ng-app="CarApp" class="containr">
  <div ng-view>
    <!-- partial will go here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

/js/main.js

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        controllers: './controllers',
        app: './app'
    }
});
requirejs(['controllers', 'app'],
function   (controller, app) { });
```

/js/app.js

```
var CarApp = angular.module('CarApp', ['ngResource'])

CarApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {controller: ListCtrl, templateUrl: '/partials/list.html'}) 
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'})
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
})
```

After loading the app.js file using require.js, it is not able to access 'CarApp' module inside app.js. why is this happening? How can I access 'CarApp module' through main.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your files loaded with RequireJS are not loaded on the page ready event, the time that Angular tries to bootstrap. That is why the CarApp module is not found.

You should bootstrap Angular manually ([ref](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)):

1. Remove the `ng-app` directive, replace it with an id:

   ```
   <div id="mainContainer" class="containr">
   ```
2. Bootstrap manually in `main.js`:

   ```
   requirejs(['controllers', 'app'], function(controller, app) {
       angular.element(document).ready(function() {
           angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('mainContainer'), ['myApp']);
       });
   });
   ```

---

Also check out [angular-require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy) for some, potentially useful, ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the good information. These changes not only loads the files as before but is also getting into app.js. One thing i would like to know is once the process enters app.js immediately after the line var CarApp = angular.module('CarApp', ['ngResource']) the program doesnt enter into the CarApp.config to process routes.. I dnt see any error in console too.. how to find why it is not entering into the CarApp.config